# Dock randomly switches between screens. Any way to stop?

Tags: macos, imac, dock

I have a iMac running OS 10.9.3 that has 2 monitors connected to it.

Randomly, thourhgout the day the dock will flip either to the left or right screen. Its pretty annoying.

Does anyone know what is causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dock position could be changed when You place Your mouse on the bottom edge of the secondary screen and then move it down again.

Comment: For me, it usually just moves randomly to the second screen when the mouse is no where near the bottom.

Comment: It depends on the displays arrangement. They have to be arranged side-by-side for the "bottom move" to work, otherwise the dock just moves randomly. So annoying!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I came across this and thought I would share my solution.

My fix is to disable separate spaces by going to "Preferences > Mission Control" then disable "Displays have separate Spaces.

The only downside to this is that you will now loose the second menu bar as well.
Thankfully there is also a app for that if this is something you want.
Its called "SecondBar" and can be downloaded from here.
http://blog.boastr.net/

Comment: This Setting has moved into `Preferences › Desktop and Dock`, at the very bottom. Checked this in Ventura, but it’s probably been moved there some versions before.